# Java playboard initialization

Tags: java

i'm new to Java and i'm now resolving this problem. I got a playboard (AxA), so its 2d array and in every box i need to have information about row and col, but also about 8 object, that are around this box. This is now its done

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            Field neighbours[] = new Field[8];

            neighbours[0] = x-1 >= 0 && x-1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x-1][y] : null;
            neighbours[1] = x-1 >= 0 && x-1 < 8 && y+1 >= 0 && y+1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x-1][y+1] : null;
            neighbours[2] = y+1 >= 0 && y+1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x][y+1] : null;
            neighbours[3] = x+1 >= 0 && x+1 < 8 && y+1 >= 0 && y+1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x+1][y+1] : null;
            neighbours[4] = x+1 >= 0 && x+1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x+1][y] : null;
            neighbours[5] = x+1 >= 0 && x+1 < 8 && y-1 >= 0 && y-1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x+1][y-1] : null;
            neighbours[6] = y-1 >= 0 && y-1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x][y-1] : null;
            neighbours[7] = x-1 >= 0 && x-1 < 8 && y-1 >= 0 && y-1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x-1][y-1] : null;

            System.out.println("X: "+x+", Y: "+y);
            for(int i = 0; i < neighbours.length; i++)
                System.out.println("    "+neighbours[i]);

            this.playBoard[x][y] = new FieldClass(x, y, neighbours);
         }
    }
```

Only problem with is, that if i try to save some box as neighbour, that i havent iterated over, so there is no object i get null, it's logical, because that object is not initialized, so i cant have it there.
How i can make it so it will work propertly ?

Comment: Do it in two steps - initialize the board, and then iterate over it to find the neighbours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        this.playBoard[x][y] = new FieldClass(x, y);
     }
}

for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        Field neighbours[] = new Field[8];

        neighbours[0] = x-1 >= 0 && x-1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x-1][y] : null;
        neighbours[1] = x-1 >= 0 && x-1 < 8 && y+1 >= 0 && y+1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x-1][y+1] : null;
        neighbours[2] = y+1 >= 0 && y+1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x][y+1] : null;
        neighbours[3] = x+1 >= 0 && x+1 < 8 && y+1 >= 0 && y+1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x+1][y+1] : null;
        neighbours[4] = x+1 >= 0 && x+1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x+1][y] : null;
        neighbours[5] = x+1 >= 0 && x+1 < 8 && y-1 >= 0 && y-1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x+1][y-1] : null;
        neighbours[6] = y-1 >= 0 && y-1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x][y-1] : null;
        neighbours[7] = x-1 >= 0 && x-1 < 8 && y-1 >= 0 && y-1 < 8 ? this.playBoard[x-1][y-1] : null;

        System.out.println("X: "+x+", Y: "+y);
        for(int i = 0; i < neighbours.length; i++)
            System.out.println("    "+neighbours[i]);

        this.playBoard[x][y].setNeighbours(neighbours));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you add [x,y] as a neighbor of [u,v] make sure that you add [u,v] as a neighbor of [x,y]

You will have to split your ternary operator into traditional if statements to do that, though.